# Accessing Json fields with weird characters

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json string im converting to object with a simple eval(string);

```
heres the sample of the json string:
var json = @'
"{ description" : { "#cdata-section" : "<some html here>" } }
';
var item = eval('('+json+')');
```

I am trying to access it like so

```
item.description.#cdata-section
```

my problem is that javascript does not like the # in the field name.. is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
item.description['#cdata-section']
```

Comment: thank you!  i had previously tried item.description[1] but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that all Javascript objects are just hash tables underneath, so you can always access elements with subscript notation.

Whenever an element name would cause a problem with the dot notation (such as using a variable element name, or one with weird characters, etc.) just use a string instead.

```
var cdata = item.description["#cdata-section"];
```

Answer (score 1):

While the official spec for [JSON](http://www.json.org/) specifies simply for chars to be provided as a field identifier, when you parse your JSON into a Javascript object, you now fall under the restrictions of a Javascript identifier.

In the Javascript spec, an identifier can start with either a letter, underscore or $.  Subsequent chars may be any letter, digit, underscore or $.

So basically, the # is valid under the JSON spec but not under Javascript.