# Parsing JSON w/ @ at sign symbol in it (arobase)

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, at-sign

My JSON object evaluates to:

```
{ "@io": IO, "@type": XXX }
```

If this variable is called `my_json`, how do I access the `@type` value of XXX? I tried `my_json.@type`, but this is giving errors. Help appreciated. Thanks,

Nick

Comment: My first inclination would be to do a string replace on your the HTTP response before parsing it. Maybe replace all instances of "@" with "at_" or something.

Comment: I am not understanding why this question got voted down, and since many people wonder how to access an object property or method which has odd naming, or when they only have a var containing the property name in a string, I will upvote.

Comment: because i believe it as been answered multiple times in this forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710103/accessing-json-fields-with-weird-characters

Comment: @Aaron Saunders: The question you linked is quite different...

Answer (score 44):

Use square bracket notation with a string:

```
var XXXValue = my_json['@type'];
```

The same can be used when you have a property name in a variable.  Using your same example:

```
var propertyName = '@type';
var XXXValue = my_json[propertyName];
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the @ symbol inside of a json file? Does it have any added meaning inside of the json context?

Comment: @David in a string such as it is, it has no specific meaning in any context (JSON, JS, etc) within the question. I have no idea why the OP has keys named like that, but it isn't of any significance in the technologies discussed.

Comment: Quite an old question but it comes up in Google searches.  The @ symbol in JSON is JSON-LD (JSON for Linked Data).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD

Comment: @boulder_ruby I think it is often used to put it on top of alphabetical sort in order to make it stand out (important metadata, ...)

Comment: The @ symbole is often use when you convert XML to JSON, i.e. the properties of a node will get mapped to @, so <product id="p1"/> will generate a JSON with "@id":"p1"

Answer (score 11):

As you've discovered, you can't use an @ symbol in a Javascript variable name, `my_json.@type` is invalid.

The good news for you is that you can access your variables as array subscripts. You would do it like this:

```
my_json["@type"]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you should use the word "array" here.

Answer (score 1):

If it ends up evaluating you can take the object and probably grab it by the key.

ie obj["@type"]. But something does seem a bit off.