# Cannot access Object key "@attributes" for itunes RSS feed

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse an itunes RSS feed by converting it to JSON via php and then inserting it with jQuery .ajax.

First is the php

```
<?php
     $url = "http://schoolceoshow.libsyn.com/rss";
     $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
     $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
     $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
     $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
     $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
     echo $json;
?>
```

Now the javascript

```
var root = location.origin + "/";

$.ajax({
url:root + "php/podcast.php",
type:"GET",
data:"json",
success:function(data){
    var dataObject = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(dataObject.channel.item[0].enclosure);
},
error:function(){
    console.log("failed");
}
});
```

What that logs out is

```
Object {@attributes: Object}
  @attributes: Object
    length: "25583209"
    type: "audio/mpeg"
    url: "http://traffic.libsyn.com/schoolceoshow/SchoolCEOShow-007.mp3"
```

My only issue here is accessing the @attributes key. How do I access a key with an @ symbol? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `dataObject['@attributes']` ?

Comment: Was coming to say I found the answer and that's it. Found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932745/parsing-json-w-symbol-in-it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to access the object with bracket notation. What I've added to my code is

```
var enclosure = dataObject.channel.item[0].enclosure;
console.log(enclosure["@attributes"]);
```

Answer was found at : [Parsing JSON w/ @ at sign symbol in it (arobase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932745/parsing-json-w-symbol-in-it)