# Parse XML Converted to JSON with # and @

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, xml, loops

I am using [This](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) XMLToJson convertion script to convert XML to JSON.

This works fine, however the JSON left over contains # and @ for some of the element values.

```
{"#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 09:48:23 +1200"}
```

I am using an $.each loop to iterate through all the items in the newly created JSON file. When I attempt the date below. I get an illegal char error, even with a \ to cancel it out.

```
> `console.log(entry.pubDate.#text));`
```

I could use JSON.stringify and then substring out the parts I don't wont, but that is messy and betrays the point of converting it to JSON in the first place.

What is the best way to get this `pubDate.#text` value to string?

The JSON Tree looks like this:

```
{
   "rss":{
      "@attributes":{
         "xmlns:dc":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
         "version":"2.0"
      },
      "channel":{
         "title":{
            "#text":"Stuff.co.nz - Stuff"
         },
         "link":{
            "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz"
         },
         "description":{
            "#text":"Top Stories from Stuff.co.nz. New Zealand, world, sport, business & entertainment news on Stuff.co.nz."
         },
         "language":{
            "#text":"en-nz"
         },
         "copyright":{
            "#text":"Fairfax New Zealand Ltd."
         },
         "dc:language":{
            "#text":"en-nz"
         },
         "dc:rights":{
            "#text":"Fairfax New Zealand Ltd."
         },
         "item":[
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"Wintry winds as heavy rains move on"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/national/68604072/Wintry-winds-as-heavy-rains-move-on"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"The heavy rains that brought flooding to the lower North Island have mostly moved on now, but a cold southwesterly keeps things feeling wintry."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431728712/600/11778600.jpg",
                     "length":"2811",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{

               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68604072"
               },
               "dc:creator":{

               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 09:48:23 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 09:48:23 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"Couple celebrates ill baby's birthday in unique way"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/life-style/well-good/inspire-me/68601237/Couple-celebrates-ill-babys-birthday-in-unique-way"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"Baby Jai Bishop has lived at Starship Hospital for the past seven months, with his parents flying back and forth from Hokitika to be by his side."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431727477/539/11778539.jpg",
                     "length":"3575",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{
                  "#text":"Aileen Nakhle"
               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68601237"
               },
               "dc:creator":{
                  "#text":"Aileen Nakhle"
               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:03:57 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:03:57 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"Sikh man removes turban to help child"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/national/68604241/Sikh-man-removes-turban-to-help-child"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"A young Sikh man has been praised for breaking religious protocol and using his turban to cradle the head of an injured child in Auckland."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431722799/399/11778399.jpg",
                     "length":"4017",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{

               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68604241"
               },
               "dc:creator":{

               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 08:46:26 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 08:46:26 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"White kiwi chicks killed at Pukaha Mt Bruce"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/environment/68574558/White-kiwi-chicks-killed-at-Pukaha-Mt-Bruce"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"Two rare white kiwi chicks are among seven kiwis killed by an \"evil\" predator at Pukaha Mt Bruce National Wildlife Centre."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431727078/519/11778519.jpg",
                     "length":"3785",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{
                  "#text":"Caleb Harris"
               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68574558"
               },
               "dc:creator":{
                  "#text":"Caleb Harris"
               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Fri, 15 May 2015 23:17:16 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Fri, 15 May 2015 23:17:16 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"LIVE: Prince Harry in New Zealand - Day 8"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/auckland/local-news/68594486/LIVE-Prince-Harry-in-New-Zealand-Day-8"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"Prince Harry is spending the morning at the Cloud in Auckland, where he's set to take on schoolkids in a quick football match. "
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431729920/638/11778638.jpg",
                     "length":"3975",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{

               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68594486"
               },
               "dc:creator":{

               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:44:54 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:44:54 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"Man pleads guilty to killing stepfather with 'atomic wedgie'"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/world/americas/68604525/Man-pleads-guilty-to-killing-stepfather-with-atomic-wedgie"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"An American man has pleaded guilty to manslaughter after he killed his stepfather with an \"atomic wedgie\"."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431727773/570/11778570.jpg",
                     "length":"2635",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{

               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68604525"
               },
               "dc:creator":{

               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:06:21 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:06:21 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"Worker injured in Auckland power outage"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/auckland/68604712/Worker-injured-in-Auckland-power-outage"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"A worker has been injured in an incident which resulted in power being cut to up to 10,000 homes on Auckland's North Shore this morning, lines company Vector says."
               },
               "author":{
                  "#text":"Henry Cooke"
               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68604712"
               },
               "dc:creator":{
                  "#text":"Henry Cooke"
               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 11:01:48 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 11:01:48 +1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "title":{
                  "#text":"U2's The Edge falls off stage"
               },
               "link":{
                  "#text":"http://www.stuff.co.nz/entertainment/celebrities/68604341/U2s-The-Edge-falls-off-stage"
               },
               "description":{
                  "#text":"U2 guitarist The Edge says he's fine after falling off the stage at a concert in Canada."
               },
               "enclosure":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "url":"http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1431728971/605/11778605.jpg",
                     "length":"2611",
                     "type":""
                  }
               },
               "author":{

               },
               "guid":{
                  "@attributes":{
                     "isPermaLink":"false"
                  },
                  "#text":"stuff.co.nz/68604341"
               },
               "dc:creator":{

               },
               "dc:date":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:29:09 +1200"
               },
               "pubDate":{
                  "#text":"Sat, 16 May 2015 10:29:09 +1200"
               }
            }
         ],
         "ttl":{
            "#text":"30"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON w/ @ symbol in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932745/parsing-json-w-symbol-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reference JSON using brackets. So while:

```
console.log(entry.pubDate.#text);
```

might fail due to `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, you could just do this:

```
console.log(entry.pubDate["#text"]);
```

I would recommend just interfacing the JSON in this way, rather than parsing the `#` and `@` characters out.

So let's say I have a really weird object, called `a` that looks like:

```
{  
   "#data":{  
      "@values":[  
         1,
         2,
         3
      ]
   }
}
```

I can get the first integer from `values` from it by calling: `a["#data"]["@values"][0]`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: As a matter of semantics, no, you can't "_reference JSON using square brackes_." You can parse (unserialize) JSON into JavaScript, in which object properties may be accessed via square bracket notation. Remeber, JSON is a string.