Why has an @ symbol been prepended to some of my JSON values?
I am trying to develop webhook for SES notifications for bounces and I am getting this weird syntax. The top level seem to be valid JSON although Message part has @ prepended in some of the sections:
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "<redacted>",
  "TopicArn": "<redacted>",
  "Message": "{\"notificationType\":\"Bounce\",\"bounce\":{\"feedbackId\":\"<redacted>\",\"bounceType\":\"Transient\",\"bounceSubType\":\"General\",\"bouncedRecipients\":[@\"emailAddress\":\"test@tessssssess.ssssssssssss\",\"action\":\"failed\",\"status\":\"5.4.4\",\"diagnosticCode\":\"smtp; 550 5.4.4 Invalid domain\"],\"timestamp\":\"2024-09-27T09:19:34.000Z\",\"reportingMTA\":\"dns; amazonses.com\"},\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2024-09-27T09:19:34.174Z\",\"source\":\"<redacted>\",\"sourceArn\":\"<redacted>\",\"sourceIp\":\"<redacted>\",\"callerIdentity\":\"<redacted>\",\"sendingAccountId\":\"<redacted>\",\"messageId\":\"<redacted>\",\"destination\":[\"test@tessssssess.ssssssssssss\"],\"headersTruncated\":false,\"headers\":[@\"name\":\"Received\",\"value\":\"<redacted>\",@\"name\":\"X-Mailer\",\"value\":\"Drupal\",@\"name\":\"x-domain-clientid\",\"value\":\"<redacted>\",@\"name\":\"x-domain-from\",\"value\":\"<redacted>\",@\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"New published announcement\",@\"name\":\"Sender\",\"value\":\"\\\"<redacted>\\\" \",@\"name\":\"To\",\"value\":\"test@tessssssess.ssssssssssss\",@\"name\":\"Message-ID\",\"value\":\"<<redacted>>\",@\"name\":\"From\",\"value\":\"\\\"<redacted>\\\" \",@\"name\":\"MIME-Version\",\"value\":\"1.0\",@\"name\":\"Date\",\"value\":\"Fri, 27 Sep 2024 04:19:34 -0500\",@\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"multipart/alternative; boundary=P8PG8xx0\"],\"commonHeaders\":@\"from\":[\"\\\"<redacted>\\\" \"],\"sender\":\"\\\"<redacted>\\\" \",\"date\":\"Fri, 27 Sep 2024 04:19:34 -0500\",\"to\":[\"test@tessssssess.ssssssssssss\"],\"messageId\":\"<redacted>\",\"subject\":\"<redacted>\"}}",
  "Timestamp": "2024-09-27T09:19:34.610Z",
  "SignatureVersion": "1",
  "Signature": "<redacted>",
  "SigningCertURL": "<redacted>",
  "UnsubscribeURL": "<redacted>"
}

I'm kind of confused as to what those "@" symbols are for e.g.:
[@\"emailAddress\":\"test@tessssssess.ssssssssssss\"
@\"name\":

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932745/parsing-json-w-at-sign-symbol-in-it-arobase
