# json and jquery to extract a @string

Tags: jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Json fields with weird characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710103/accessing-json-fields-with-weird-characters)
>   [Parsing JSON w/ @ symbol in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932745/parsing-json-w-symbol-in-it)

hi to everybody this is my first time here and sorry for my English
so I have a problem extracting a string from json result the string look like this @string. here is a example for a result format

```
"RateInfo": {
            "@priceBreakdown": "true",
            "@promo": "false",
            "@rateChange": "false",
            "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                "@averageBaseRate": "93.33",
                "@averageRate": "93.33",
                "@commissionableUsdTotal": "93.33",
                "@currencyCode": "USD",
                "@maxNightlyRate": "93.33",
                "@nightlyRateTotal": "93.33",
                "@surchargeTotal": "16.33",
                "@total": "109.66",
                "NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
```

i need to get out a @total. any help please

Comment: Why are you sending what appears to be XML data as json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already parsed your JSON string into a JavaScript object e.g.:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you can simply access the `@total` property like normal:

```
var total = obj.RateInfo.ChargeableRateInfo["@total"];
```

Notice that you have to use square brackets to access the `@total` property, since the `@` character is invalid in JavaScript identifiers.

Comment: i don't understand parsed is the waye how i call a json?

Comment: to call the json response a use curl PHP than i try to print it using jquery json like this:

Comment: $.each(data, function(){

Comment: thnks James Allardice i have check info about JSON.parse and i will say about gracias

Answer (score -1):

Why not send XML as XML, rather than converting it to JSON?

```
<RateInfo priceBreakdown="true" promo="false" rateChange="false">
     <ChargeableRateInfo averageBaseRate="93.33" averageRate="93.33"
              commissionableUsdTotal="93.33" currencyCode="USD"
              maxNightlyRate="93.33"  nightlyRateTotal="93.33"
              surchargeTotal="16.33" total="109.66">
         <NightlyRatesPerRoom>
               ...
         </NightlyRatesPerRoom>
    </ChargeableRateInfo>
</RateInfo>
```

Comment: tanks user566527 but i try to do it using json at faster than xml i already know how using xml

Comment: @user1447313: Are you sure json is faster than XML? a json-encoded xml packet is about the same size as the original XML.

Comment: yeah it true but using alot arrays and functions foreach... json comes faster... maybe me i dont usi it good